# React-Native "Kotlin could not find the required JDK tools in the Java installation"

Tags: java, android, react-native, kotlin

I have a react-native app and I'm trying to run a ios simulator next to an android simulator (if that's possible) to see both UIs as I work. But everytime I try running `npm start android` I get this error:

```
> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin'.
> Failed to query the value of task ':react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin' property 'compilerRunner$kotlin_gradle_plugin'.
   > Kotlin could not find the required JDK tools in the Java installation. Make sure Kotlin compilation is running on a JDK, not JRE.
```

I'm not sure what this means and can't figure out how fix this. I've never used Kotlin, Java, or React-Native so all of this seems confusing.

What exactly is happening, I didn't change any files so why is there even an error happening, it worked fine with ios simulator in XCode so I downloaded Android Studio to run a android simulator and now this error keeps happening.